# Java: A String-type return must be cast to one out of 3 different types. How can I do it avoiding switch/case?

Tags: java

I browsed around for a few answers but had no luck. Actually, it is kinda complicated to explain what I'm trying to do with words, so let's see some snipets:

I have 4 attributes:

```
private int pageCount; //type 1
private int[] monoColorCount; //type 2
private float cost;  //type 3
private int type;
```

But at any time, an object will have value to only one of these. They are fed by a method that returns a string (parsed from a XML) and depending on the type I will know which one has value. My first attempt was a switch/case, a solution that works but is far from efficient:

```
switch(type){
        case 1: pageCount = Integer.parseInt(QuotasBalance.getUserQuota(user, domain)); break;
        case 2: StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(QuotasBalance.getUserQuota(user, domain), "|");
                monoColorCount = new int[]{Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken()), Integer.parseInt(st.nextToken())}; break;
        case 3: cost = Float.parseFloat(QuotasBalance.getUserQuota(user, domain));
    }
```

Maybe I should've mentioned before: I'm strung to Java 1.4, therefore the StringTokenizer. In this case, I'd have to use a switch/case on type every time I needed this value from an external class:

```
switch(myQuotaInstance.getType){
        case 1: /*Do something with pageCount*/
        case 2: /*Do something with monoColorCount*/
        case 3: /*Do something with cost*/
    }
```

Needless to say, that's ridiculous. I also tried polymorphism and reflection, but since I fail to grasp completely the concept of reflection yet, that was another dead end. I tried creating a different class to encapsulate only those three attributes which only accounted for delegating the inevitable. Well, I think I made myself clear. Now I'm open to suggestions on how to tackle this problem.

Comment: Stuck in Java 1.4? You know Java 5 came out EIGHT years ago right?

Comment: I knew some smart-ass would say something like that, I should've been better prepared. I'm currently developing an embedded application to a Multifunctional Printer and their VM is merely a subset of Java 1.4 with some custom classes of their own for user interface. So, there you have it.

Comment: I don't understand something about your `QuotaBalance`. Is it return 3 different strings being called 3 times with same arguments? Can you post a code of entire method where you try to parse these fields?

Comment: @glowcoder,... and you know Java 5.0 was EOL almost 1.5 years ago.

Comment: @glowcoder: some people have to support COBOL apps believe me or not.

Comment: Like I said, this return string is a parse from a XML (actually, it parses the result of a webservice call), and <Value> tag in this XML might be a single number, a pair (hence, an int array) or currency value (treated as a float). What feeds this XML are settings from a different software altogether. It wouldn't help much posting code, I hope you got it.

Comment: Casting is a keyword in Java with a well defined scope. If a class B is derived from A (or from a class, which is derived from A), and an instance of B was assigned to an A, you can cast that A to an B. And only then. And since String is declared final, you can never cast String to anything. So you should change your the headline of your question, if possible.

Answer (score 2):

You could grab the strategy pattern. First have an interface.

```
public interface Strategy {
    void execute(QuotaInstance instance);
}
```

Then have a mapping

```
private Map strategies = new HashMap();

{
    strategies.put(Integer.valueOf(1), new PageCountStrategy());
    // ...
}
```

Then execute it as follows

```
((Strategy) strategies.get(Integer.valueOf(type))).execute(myQuotaInstance);
```

Inside the `execute()` you just access/modify the instance.

Comment: Note that I initially posted this answer with Java 1.5 in mind (generics, autoboxing), sorry, I have edited it :)

Comment: There you go, I knew there must be a design pattern for that! Let me try it out!

Comment: Even in 1.4, I think there was `Integer.valueOf(int)`

Comment: Note that you might need to pass some context holding the variables of interest instead of `QuotaInstance`, depending on job which needs to be done. @Yishai: that's a better choice, indeed.

Answer (score 1):

@BalusC why `Strategy` is better here over `State`? I would suggest state, because it seems natural to me in that type of code, but I remember your "infamous post" about patters, so I guess you are right ;)

Comment: You can be right. The larger context of the problem is not clear enough to give a definitive answer on that (that's also a bit the reason why I started the answer with "you *could* ") ;)

Comment: @Balusc well, after a while, now I think that as long as changing state of existing object is not needed (it can by only in one state - var `int type` in given code cannot be changed) `Strategy` is optimal choice :)

Answer (score 0):

Do your Quota objects change their type during their lifetime?

If not, better create three different classes (which can have a common interface or baseclass).

```
class CostQuota extends Quota {
}

class PageCountQuota extends Quota {
}

class ColorPageCountQuota extends Quota {
}
```

Each of them can have a string constructor which does the parsing, so you only need a single type switch at creating the object. (But you could also have them be serialized to different XML elements, so no need for the type int at all.)

Answer (score 0):

Well... I studied both Strategy and State patterns and they were totally overkill. Actually, I solved the problem in a very simple (even kinda n00bish) way: I was casting the return value from string to its proper type in my app 3rd layer. When I realised that this value type wouldn't matter until it got to the first layer (UI), I decided to pass it along as a string anyway and in the first layer, I'd switch it (the very way I was doing in the 3rd) and along with the casting, I'm calling a different method to build the UI itself, for it relies on this value type to be built but doesn't rely on the value itself. Yeah, not "elegant" or anything, but in this domain, I think it suits well (overall, the Quota class can be static, actually).

But thanks for the comments, I've gone after both state and strategy patterns and ended up learning (actually, "re-learning") some patterns that will be VERY useful anywhere - such as Method Template and Factory.

Method Template is so obvious, yet so overlooked... ^^